# How to jump cursor to next textbox on enter key press

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Here i have dynamically created textboxes based on button click

So when i have my cursor in first textbox and when i key press enter button it should jump to next textboxes. How can I do that

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim count As Integer
        Dim textbox As New TextBox()
        count = Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToList().Count
        textbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(60, 25 * count)
        textbox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(80, 20)
        textbox.Name = "textbox_" & (count + 1)
        Panel1.Controls.Add(textbox)
    End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) event for your `TextBox` controls and check if the is <kbd>Enter</kbd>, select next control:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        Dim txt = New TextBox()
        txt.Name = String.Format("textbox_{0}", i)
        AddHandler txt.KeyDown, AddressOf txt_KeyDown
        Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txt)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub txt_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If (e.KeyData = Keys.Enter) Then
        e.Handled = True
        SendKeys.Send("{Tab}")
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note:**

- It's better to use [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21wykkx(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9e8s203(v=vs.100).aspx) to add dynamic controls.
- Add handler can be done also this way:

  ```
  AddHandler txt.KeyDown, Sub(s, ea)
                              If (ea.KeyData = Keys.Enter) Then
                                  ea.Handled = True
                                  SendKeys.Send("{Tab}")
                              End If
                          End Sub
  ```